# Python - trying to categorise article based on a list of keywords and associated ids

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to categorise an article based on a db table that comprises two columns as follows:

```
id   keywords
1    cat, kitten, tiger
2    dog, puppy, jackal
```

If I have an article how do I identify which keywords appear in it and thus which id I need to use to categorise the article? My code is as follows so far:

```
cur.execute("SELECT keywords, id FROM Keywords")
keywords = cur.fetchall()
keywords = [k[0] for k in keywords]
if any(word in article for word in keywords):
    matched = [word for word in keywords if word in article]
    print("Matched keywords: %s" % ', '.join(matched))
```

Comment: What's the current output of the code, if any?

Answer (score 1):

If keywords is a comma separated list of keywords, you'll want to split that string. Try something like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT keywords, id FROM Keywords")
result = cur.fetchall()
keywords = []
for row in result:
    keywords += row[0].split(',')
if any(word in article for word in keywords):
    matched = [word for word in keywords if word in article]
    print("Matched keywords: %s" % ', '.join(matched))
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - you're a star!!

Comment: How do I identify the id for the given set of keywords?